# docker phpmyadmin cant access localhost

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, phpmyadmin

I try to create a phpmyadmin docker, the command executed successfully but when i access to localhost:8080 it freezes and nothing appears.

I created my docker phpmyadmin with : 
`docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql:mysql -e MYSQL_USERNAME=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 8080:80 -d phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`

My database is created with : 
`sudo docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -v /home/user/dev/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:latest`

Im on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks for help.

EDIT :

`docker logs myadmin`

```
2017-05-02 01:03:28,815 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)

2017-05-02 01:03:28,815 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/nginx.ini" during parsing
2017-05-02 01:03:28,815 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/php.ini" during parsing
2017-05-02 01:03:28,844 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-05-02 01:03:28,844 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-05-02 01:03:28,844 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-05-02 01:03:29,846 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 22
2017-05-02 01:03:29,847 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 23
2017-05-02 01:03:31,355 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-05-02 01:03:31,355 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

`sudo docker ps | grep 8080`

```
cbbc1c23ba2c        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp     myadmin
```

Comment: what is the result of `curl localhost:8080` ?

Comment: It's working for me. It is not freezing. After run the container, are they still alive? `docker ps`

Comment: After a long time : `curl: (56)  Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` , the container is still alive

Comment: Try adding: `-e PMA_HOST=mysql`. As this: `docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql:mysql -e PMA_HOST=mysql -e MYSQL_USERNAME=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 8080:80 -d phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` . I needed that but I've never had the freezing problem

Comment: Please, post `docker logs myadmin`, and `docker ps | grep 8080`

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: The permission denied seems to be because you need to run docker with sudo, `sudo docker ps | grep 8080`

Comment: Ups sorry, its good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my ubuntu and  my contenairs, phpmyadmin is now visible. (curl localhost:8080 show me the code correctly now).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I was creating my containers from docker image `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1.1-fpm-alpine`.

It solved after I crated my container from official image of phpmyadmin and used tag latest.